# Implement "return" of sequential languages in Haskell

Tags: haskell, evaluation, fold, short-circuiting

Currently reading through the Learn You a Haskell, and I've come across this example for searching if a sublist is inside a list:

```hs
searchSublist :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
searchSublist needle haystack =
  let nlen = length needle
  in foldl (\acc x -> if take nlen x ==  needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```

Algorithm optimality aside (Horspool's algorithm comes to mind), it seems inefficient for Haskell to use folds and keep iterating through values when it could just "stop" when it hits "True". I.e., say, in `Python`, we could have something like...

```py
def sublist_exists(needle, haystack):
  nlen = len(needle)
  if len(haystack) < nlen:
    return False
  elif haystack[:nlen] == needle:
    return True
  else:
    return sublist_exists(needle, haystack[1:])
```

and we would stop if we hit a `True` condition.

However, for the `Haskell` code, if I switch the `fold` to a `scan`, I get...

```hs
searchSublist :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
searchSublist needle haystack =
  let nlen = length needle
  in scanl (\acc x -> if take nlen x ==  needle then True else acc) False (tails haystack)
```

```hs
ghci> searchSublist [3,4,5] [1..5]
[False,False,False,True,True,True,True]
```

Seems inefficient to traverse through the entire list.

Comment: If you use `foldr` and Haskell's laziness, then this will stop from the moment it finds an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems inefficient for Haskell to use folds and keep iterating through values when it could just "stop" when it hits `True`.

If you use `foldr` and use tha laziness that `(||)` uses, it can stop from the moment it finds an element. For example `take nlen x` will not first calculate the entire list, this will be done lazily as well, so the `(==)` function will check elementwise, and from the moment one of the two elements is different, it will stop.

We can use of [**`isPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) to check if one list is the prefix of the other, which is more elegant than writing this with `take nlen`.

We can thus implement this as:

```
searchSublist :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
searchSublist needle = foldr ((||) . isPrefixOf needle) False . tails
```

or with [**`any :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any):

```
searchSublist :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
searchSublist needle = any (isPrefixOf needle) . tails
```

There is also an [**`isInfixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) function which seems to do what you here implement.

Comment: Why does `foldr` allow laziness but `foldl` won't?

Comment: @AlexColeman: because it is implemented as ``foldl f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == (...((z `f` x1) `f` x2) `f`...) `f` xn``, so that means that it reaches the last item to apply the function. Whereas foldr is implemented as `foldr f  z [x1,x2,...,xn] = f x1 (f x2 (f x3 ... (f xn z)))`, so if the `f` "cuts off" after seeing the value of `x1`, then it will never evaluate the `f x2` tree. A consequence is that `foldl` also works on *finite* lists, whereas `foldr` can for certain fold functions work on infinite lists: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:foldl